# How to Replace unwanted characters or Special characters in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

How can I remove unwanted characters on an input text using PHP. I have a working version of javascript which blocks specific characters. However, its still can bypass the script if the user's javascript is disabled. So I'm interested on making a PHP version.

my working javascript for blocking specific characters "<>[]#='";()$&"

```
<input id="cleanify" placeholder="Some text here">

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#cleanify').bind('keyup blur', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[<>#=';",$&(\)[\]]/g,'_'))
});

</script>
```

Comment: Well, do the same thing in PHP. Did you try that?

Comment: I didn't know it will work on PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use PHP's preg_replace wherever you are submitting the form to.

ie.

```
$cleanify = preg_replace('/[<>#=\';",$&(\)[\]]/', '_');
```

Comment: yes, thanks @FrankerZ, but how can I make a working sample on php, Because the inputs must be cleaned before submitting the form.

Comment: @AlexNewbie Exactly like the example here... put this in the handler in which you handle the form submit

Comment: @AlexNewbie If it is the solution to your question you should accept the answer.